# Reading in a grid to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, 2d

I'm working on a basic board game and i'm having an issue with file reading. I'm trying to read in a grid like so:

```html
1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 2 3 1 1
1 1 1 3 1 1
1 1 1 4 1 1
1 2 2 2 4 1
```

My plan is to associate each number with something different after the grid has been read in a 2D array (1 would be a wall, 2 would be a path etc). Any help would be appreciated.

*Note* Read: use a file reader to scan the text file in order to place the grid in a 2d array

*Note* : I am working on the game in LibGDX

Comment: What something different?

Comment: You mean to replace 1 with wall etc?

Comment: What do you mean "read"?

Comment: Read: use a file reader to scan the text file in order to place the grid in a 2d array

Comment: This question is tagged both _Java_ and _JavaScript_. These are two different languages with a similar name, but question itself doesn't give clues as to which you mean.

Comment: @PaulS. I'll be more precise then: I am working on the game in LibGDX using Java.

Comment: @timval thanks for editing that in, you may find this reference helpful https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#reading-from-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgdx's FileHandle has a helper method to easily read a text file into a String. The following should work with non-square or jagged arrays of arbitrary size. Assuming your file is in the assets directory:

```
String fileString = Gdx.files.internal("myFile.txt").readString();
String[] lines = fileString.split("\n");
int[][] theArray = new int[lines.length][];
for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
    String[] elements = lines[i].split(" ");
    theArray[i] = new String[elements.length];
    for (int j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
        theArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(elements[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *read in* means *convert this String to an Array of Arrays of Numbers*.

```
var str = "1 1 2 1 1 1\n1 1 2 1 1 1\n1 1 2 3 1 1\n1 1 1 3 1 1\n1 1 1 4 1 1\n1 2 2 2 4 1";

var arr = str.split('\n').map(e => e.split(' ').map(Number));

/*
[
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1]
]
*/
```

What's going on?

1. We divide the *String* up based on new lines `'\n'`
2. We divide each of those divisions up based on a space, `' '`
3. We convert each of the results from *2* into a *Number*

---

As [Andy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296756/reading-in-a-grid-to-a-2d-array/34296842#comment56335395_34296842), I used ES6 *arrow notation* for the *function* above.

```
// ES6 arrow notation
(arg1, arg2) => expr
// can be written as legacy
function (arg1, arg2) { return expr;}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that's ES6 JS not ES5.

Comment: I get what you are saying here but not what I meant.

Comment: @timval I'm going to guess that the issue with this answer is something like "but how do I get `str`?". The answer to that depends on **where** your _text file_ is located, i.e. the local machine or online, and if it is online then is it on the same origin? **please note I'm answering here from a JavaScript perspective** (as you tagged it)

Comment: @PaulS. as stated above I am working in LibGDX using Java